# Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlet Error - File skipped because it was already present

Tags: powershell, azure

Running the following Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlet for Windows Azure: `Import-Module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1'` generates the error below.  I ran PowerShell with elevated priveleges and `Get-ExecutionPolicy` returns `RemoteSigned`.

Here is the error:

> Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data  file:
>       Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Manag
>       ement.Websites.Types.ps1xml : File skipped because it was already present from "Microsoft.PowerShell".
>       Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Manag
>       ement.SqlDatabase.Types.ps1xml : File skipped because it was already present from "Microsoft.PowerShell".
>       At line:1 char:14
>       + Import-Module <<<<  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1'
>             + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

The script does not complete after this error.

Comment: Did you run that from a regular PowerShell console, the Windows Azure PowerShell console, or from a tool like PowerGUI?

Comment: From the Windows Azure PowerShell console as administrator

Comment: Did u installed powershell from thew link below: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9811175&clcid=0x409 (Try re-installing it and then when you launch Azure PS you should have it ready to go)

Comment: The installation was from your link. So I uninstall Azure PS, then re-installed from your link.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: are you explicitly loading the module? can you remove that line?

Comment: I am following the directions here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest item #5 which says to run the cmdlet: `Import-Module "C:\Program Files...`

Comment: you can try `Import-Module "C:\Program Files..." -force`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After half a day of being stuck on this, I just decided to continue with the steps, and it worked flawlessly.  So I guess it was simply a warning, but did not effect the rest of the process. I have not had any issues as a result.